# pandas datetime index serial difference

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

How do I compute the serial differences of a pandas datetime index? The `diff` function does not work:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.date_range('2018-12-31','2019-01-31').diff()

AttributeError: 'DatetimeIndex' object has no attribute 'diff'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `np.diff`, to get the difference in nanoseconds.

```
np.diff(dt)
```

From this, if you need an Index of Timedeltas, you can call `to_timedelta`.

```
pd.to_timedelta(np.diff(dt), unit='ns')
# TimedeltaIndex(['1 days', '1 days', ...], dtype='timedelta64[ns]', freq=None)
```

Or, a Series:

```
pd.Series(np.diff(dt))

0    1 days
1    1 days
2    1 days
3    1 days
4    1 days
...
```